# create a cell or contained of matrix of different size with in a loop in python

Tags: python, loops, matrix, cell

I would like to create a container, as a cell or list, of a matrix of different sizes within a loop. I created a python code like this:

```
W = []
W_tot = []
for i in range(0,layer_number):   #layer_numer = number of matrix to be created
    row_W = int(input('NumRow = ')) #number of row of the nth matrix
    col_W = int(input('Numcols = ')) #number of cols of the nth matrix
    W = 0.5*np.random.rand(row_W,col_W) #creation of the nth matrix with random number
    cells = np.array([W]) #insert of the created matrix in a cell
```

Anyway, I got always an error. Surely I make a mistake on the creation of a cell that contains all the matrix created at every step of the loop.

Comment: Please include the error

Comment: I got no error but a cell with the wrong dimension. As an example, using layer_number =2, i.e., I want to create two matrices, I got a cell with dimension (1,20,9) where 20 is the number of rows and 9 the number of columns. What I would like to obtain is a cell with dimensions (2,..).

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem using this code.

```
W = []
cells = []
for i in range(0,layer_number):
    row_W = int(input('NumRow = '))
    col_W = int(input('Numcols = '))
    W = 0.5*np.random.rand(row_W,col_W)
    cells.append([W])
```